# Serilization of collections

Tags: c#

I need to serialize a `collection` that can hold two values `object and int`.

I have a list of articles that are going to be read by a user and I want to give him the opportunity to come back to the exact sentence where he finished. This method will return three articles and the sentence id.

I used `Dictionary` to achieve this however I later I found out that `serialization` of dictionary is not that easy. Then I was thinking `array`, but I am not sure how to approach this since values should always be different, do you have experience which collection I can use?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? I suggest trying the various collection types and see how they work - you'll learn a lot more doing that.

Comment: Make a class with a property name (which would be the key in the dictionary) and additional properties for values .  The serialize the class.

Comment: @DavidG in my question i have mentioned that i have tried to use dictionary. Then i was implementing array but i had my doubts about it and decided to ask

Comment: You can use a library to serialize your types. Pick one from the list and try it out. The most versatile is BinaryFormatter and part of .NET Framework. See https://aloiskraus.wordpress.com/2019/09/29/net-serialization-benchmark-2019-roundup/